# OkHttpClient close connection

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'd like to use OkHttpClient to load a url, and if the website at the given url responds with a pdf content type I will go ahead and download the PDF, otherwise I want to ignore the response.

My question is, do I need to do anything special to close the request/response or do I need to do anything to indicate that i won't be using the response if I choose to not read the response bytestream? If not, when does OkHttpClient close the connection?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Calling `response.body().close()` will release all resources held by the response. The connection pool will keep the connection open, but that'll get closed automatically after a timeout if it goes unused.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to close the response myself or will the resources automatically be released if I just ignore them? Should I call close on the response even if I do read in the bytestream, after the read of course? Finally, if I call cancel on the request in the on finished callback, will this release the response?

Comment: In general, you need to close the response. If you read the bytestream to the end, OkHttp will release resources for you, but it's still a good practice to close it anyway. If you cancel the request, you only need to close if `onResponse` gets called. If it doesn't, then we canceled it early enough that there's nothing to close.

Comment: You can also call `response.close()` which, according to the documentation, is equivalent to `response.body().close()`.